# Speed sensor program, loop, python 3 , A level

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I need to be able to loop this code on condition, if the user wants to repeat the program, then it must be looped. if the user wants to exit the program, then all the number plates of speeding cars should be displayed. This is what I have so far:

```
import time
capturedtime=time.time()

speed_limit = 30
distance = 50

numberplates = []
newplate = ("Input number plate")

input("Press enter to start")
start_time = time.time()
input("Press enter to stop")
stop_time = time.time()
capturedtime = stop_time - start_time

print('Time taken: {:.2f} seconds'.format(capturedtime))
print('Distance: {:.2f}'.format(distance))
speed = distance / capturedtime
print('Speed: {:.2f}'.format(speed))

if speed > speed_limit:
    print("You were breaking the speed limit")
    numberplates.append(newplate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you could just put all your Code into a while loop and stop it via another input().

Example:

```
import time
exit = True
'''your variables'''
while(exit):
    '''your Code'''
    x = input("Enter 'y' if you want to exit.")
    if x.lower() == y:
        exit = False
        print("All speeding Cars:") # Print all the Cars!
        for plate in numberplates:
            print(plate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for, but try the below.

```
import time
capturedtime = time.time()

speed_limit = 30
distance = 500

numberplates = []

loops = True

while(loops):
    try:
        newplate = input("Input number plate: ")

        input("Press enter to start: ")
        start_time = time.time()
        input("Press enter to stop: ")
        stop_time = time.time()
        capturedtime = stop_time - start_time

        print('Time taken: {:.2f} seconds'.format(capturedtime))
        print('Distance: {:.2f}'.format(distance))
        speed = distance / capturedtime
        print('Speed: {:.2f}'.format(speed))

        if speed > speed_limit:
            print("You were breaking the speed limit")
            numberplates.append(newplate)

        exit = input("Press x to exit, Press enter to continue: ")
        if exit.lower() == 'x':
            loops = False
    except Exception:
        pass

print(numberplates)
```

I have just used your code inside while loop. please check the documentation on while loop for more information, https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop